# Every page after 'chapter page' is indented

Tags: page-breaking, indentation, chapters, noindentafter

I'm new to Tex, I use shareLatex specifically.
When I write my 'book' document every page that has "Chapter ..." on it is displaying fine and the text aligns to the odd-side margin (?) nicely. But then every page after that is strangely shifted to the right (I don't believe it has something to do with indentation as the chapter title at the top of the page is also shifted). This also happens with the table of contents.

Here is an image, the top page has the 'chapter' text on it and the bottom page is strangely shifted. Please excuse the quality, I have limited resources atm.
[image: Please excuse the quality, I have limited resources atm]
"Hoofdstuk 4" means chapter 4 in my native language.

My document is built up like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}    % space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}%2em}       % amount of indention
\setlength{\textwidth}{175mm}      % default = 6.5"
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-5mm}   % default = 0"
\setlength{\textheight}{225mm}     % default = 9"
\setlength{\topmargin}{-12mm}      % default = 0" -12mm


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{3cm}
        {...}\\[1cm]
        {...}\\[1cm]
        {...}
    \end{center}
...\\
...\\
... 

\begin{center}
\textit{...}\\[2cm]
\includegraphics[scale= 0.5]{picture.jpg}
\end{center}
   \let\newpage\relax  % Avoid following page break
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter 1}

\section{section 1}
etc..
```

Hopefully this can be sorted out as I have looked everywhere for a solution. Thank you for reading all this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You might look at the [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package if you have a particular set of margins in mind. It tends to be easier than working out the lower-level lengths like you've used.

Comment: you would be better to use the geometry package than setting page size by hand but as it is you have increased `\textwidth` on all pages but only reduced `\oddsidemargin` so even pages are shifted off too far you need to set `\evensidemargin`. Also `textheight` should be `\topskip` + an integer multiple of `\baselineskip` otherwise a large block of text with no vertical space on the page can never fit on the page.

Comment: Or use the `oneside` option, i.e., `\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}`.

Comment: Thanks, all of you! That's what you get for copy pasting something without truly understanding it. I thought 'odd' was in this case another term for left or something, English...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you make it an answer so I can mark it as 'the answer'? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better to use the geometry package than setting page size by hand but as it is you have increased `\textwidth` on all pages but only reduced `\oddsidemargin` so even pages are shifted off too far you need to set `\evensidemargin`.

Also `\textheight` should be `\topskip` + an integer multiple of `\baselineskip` otherwise a large block of text with no vertical space on the page can never fit on the page.

A possible set of settings for `geometry`, leaving to the package to compute the other parameters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  textwidth=175mm,
  textheight=225mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- don't forget
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  sorting=ynt,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}    % space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}%2em}       % amount of indention

\begin{document}
```